# DVD to FLV File Conversion Using PHP -- Is this Doable? Insane? What are alternatives?

Tags: php, flv, dvd, video-conversion

So I have users who have told me they are interested in being able to upload videos to my site straight from DVD's (for which they own the rights, of course).

I've never encountered this before, but I would imagine this would take an enormous amount of resources and would clog up the servers, which I would like to avoid.

A basic google search returns numerous [DVD to FLV converters](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=off&client=firefox-a&hs=XMP&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&q=dvd+to+flv&aq=0p&aqi=g-p1g3g-s1g5&aql=&oq=dvd+&gs_rfai=) but all seem to appear to be applications which would need to be used to convert the files before uploading.

So, if this isn't a horrible idea, how would I go about implementing it using PHP or any Linux command line tool?

Or if this is insane, Why is this a bad idea? and What are other possible alternatives?

As an example, I could see an alternative being:

- showing information about how to convert the files to a valid upload format before uploading

Comment: I really would do this on the client. A normal DVD is about 4 GB, which you would have to upload to the server, before you can convert it.

Answer (score 1):

Search for ffmpeg - i don't know does it reads DVD files, but most of video formats can, see:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libavcodec

It's a command line program, which can convert between many video formats.

You can't avoid huge load on server, because converting video simply require lot of computations. Maybe there is a way to restrict resources that program takes and slow it down - but it will have cost in execution time. On multi-core server, only one core will be loaded when converting video, so maybe this is not a problem ?

Remeber that uploading large files (like DVD video is) can also be a problem, and you should watch to nice uploader with progress bar (for example flash uploader)

Comment: Thanks, I use ffmpeg right now, and I did see that it supports video object (.VOB) files. However, a DVD appears to be a collection of VOB files as well as audio files, so it's not just a matter of can it be done, but how do I get the input from a DVD 'file'? How does the user select a full DVD to be uploaded?

Comment: If it is divided to parts - you can use some flash uploader that allow select multiple files to upload at once (i've used one and user could just select multiple files in windows dialog to select file, but i don't remeber how it was called)

Comment: I use SWFUpload for multiple file uploads. The user base is entirely un-technical, though, so I'm concerned they may miss a file or include more than they need to...Or that they might upload all the dvd files along with another group of files and I won't be able to differentiate. The more I think about it, the more I realize could go wrong. It would be a lot easier to just select the dvd and upload it altogether. It looks as though flash doesn't support selecting a folder and uploading recursively tho. Maybe they soon will